# Delphi 10.3.3 raise error e2597 when linking an 64bit Android application on libibtogo.a

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi 10.3.3.
I try to build a 32 or 64 bits Android app for deploy on Application Store.
The error appears on linking part.

```
[DCC Error] E2597 c:\\program files (x86)\\embarcadero\\studio\\20.0\\lib\\Android\\Release\libibtogo.a(vportcompat.o): In function `VISPortable::sleep(unsigned long)':/Users/jenkins/Jenkins/workspace/Build CPP-Android-8.4/cpp/SanctuaryClientProject/jni/CPP/vportcompat.cpp:680: undefined reference to `__FD_SET_chk'
c:\\program files (x86)\\embarcadero\\studio\\20.0\\lib\\Android\\Release\libibtogo.a(File.o): In 
function `sanct::File::GenerateFile(sanct::File*, sanct::String const&, sanct::String const&, sanct::File const&)':
```

any advice on how to fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem after reading this post.
https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/general-development/f/installation-issues-23/70677/delphi-rio-10-3-3---problem-after-upgrade

The problem was in the 32 bits NDK not in 64 bits.